# Using Enterprise LIbrary 6 Application Blocks

Tags: enterprise-library

Then new Enterprise Library 6 is out and can be [downloaded here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789). I have downloaded and extracted EnterpriseLibrary6-binaries.exe to a folder on my C: drive. The readme says this:

```
MICROSOFT ENTERPRISE LIBRARY 6

Summary: This package contains Enterprise Library configuration console, MSMQ distributor service, merge configuration tool and a script to download binaries for all application blocks from NuGet.

In order to get all the binaries, run the install-packages.ps1 script.

Note: For the Semantic Logging Application Block Out-of-Process service, a separate package is available for download.
```

I then run Powershell and run the script. I now look in the folder I extracted the .exe to and all of the binaries are there. Now, here are the instructions from the Enterprise Library 6 .chm.

```
To install the integrated Visual Studio configuration editor 

1. On the Visual Studio Tools menu, choose Extensions and Updates. 
2. In the Extensions and Updates dialog, search online for EnterpriseLibrary.config. 
3. Click the Download button to download and install the Enterprise Library configuration editor. 
4. Restart Visual Studio to complete the installation. 


To launch and use the configuration editor from Visual Studio 

1. Open a solution in Visual Studio. 
2. If the solution does not contain a configuration file, add one using the Visual Studio Add menu. 
3. In Solution Explorer, right-click the configuration file and then click Edit Enterprise Library V6 Configuration. This launches the integrated configuration editor or the appropriate standalone version of the configuration tool.
```

Step #3 is where I am stuck. I have a WCF service project with a web.config in it. I right click the web.config and I don't see a "Edit Enterprise Library V6 Configuration" context menu option.

I DO see an "Edit Server Configuration File v6". However, when I click this I get the following error.

[image]

All I'm trying to do is use the Exception Handling Application Block in my WCF service project. I've looked around the web and can't find any easy step-by-step tutorial to guide me either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use NuGet to install the application block I wanted to use in the project. For me, Tools >> Library Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for solution and add the appropriate EntLib 6 Exception Handling Application Block WCF Provider.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the solution property for "Enterprise Library v6 binaries path" to set to
the folder that you extracted "EnterpriseLibrary6-binaries.exe".

You can do that by clicking the solution and then pressing F4 to see the properties window, but you need to make sure that your "Enterprise Library Config tool" is v6.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789

The Visual Studio Gallery provides Enterprise Library 5 Config tool which is obviously the wrong Version.

Answer (score 0):

Just download Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix
from the below link and while installing provide VS2012 or Vs2013.
 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789

After installation restart Visual Studio.
You will Enterprise Library 6.0 configuration.
By default Extension and Updates in VS give 5.0 configuration we need 6.0 to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Download `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix`, from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38789) and during installation, provide VS2012 or VS2013.

Then restart your VS2012/2013 and you should be good to go!